# How to select md-autocomplete option with Selenium or Selenide?

Tags: java, angular, selenium, testing, selenide

Here is my Java attempt, but what should I fix?

```
SelenideElement product = $(By.id("product"));
Assertions.assertEquals("Search product", product.attr("md-floating-label"));
product.find(By.tagName("input")).val("test");
SelenideElement span = product.find(By.tagName("span")); //this one and last lines does not work as expected
product.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
product.pressEnter();
```

And HTML code

```html
<md-autocomplete id="product" flex="85" md-selected-item="ctrl.orderItem.product" md-search-text="ctrl.productQuery" md-items="item in ctrl.findProduct(ctrl.productQuery)" md-item-text="item.name" md-delay="300" md-floating-label="Search product">
  <div layout="row" class="item" layout-align="start center">
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.productQuery">{{item.name}}</span>
  </div>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `product.find(By.tagName("span"));` I would try replacing it with an XPath as such:

```
SelenideElement span = product.find(By.xpath("//*[@id='product']/div/span"));
```

The issue was that `span` is not a direct child element of product (which is a `md-autocomplete` element), so you need a slightly more complex locator to find the `span`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Tried, but: "Element not found {By.xpath: //*[@id='product']/div/span}
Expected: exist"-------Probably, I should press keys not on this span, but on generated, related to option tags og dropdown.

Comment: Yes, the text should probably go to `md-autocomplete` element. Have you had any luck sending keys to `product`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont need to do this thing `Assertions.assertEquals("Search product", product.attr("md-floating-label"));`

Just try find your span element like this `SelenideElement span = $(By.xpath("//md-autocomplete[@id='product' and @md-floating-label= 'Search product"]//span'));
span.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
span.pressEnter();`
If element with label 'Search product' is not exist, you get a `SoSuchElementException`